# Anaconda can't launch python script with shebang line in Windows

Tags: python, file-extension

I have an anaconda installation in windows that I think used to be able to run python scripts with shebang lines like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("hello python")
```

at a prompt without typing "python" (I say "I think" because I've run through a few installs lately ... but I routinely use this functionality).  I believe this requires that the py extension point to a binary called py.exe which I assume is automatically installed somewhere, possibly C:\Windows. The launch no longer works (or never did) and I don't see "py.exe" on my system anywhere.

Is py.exe supposed to be part of miniconda and this is supposed to be set up automatically? Is there a right way to fix this? Do I have to get the binary?

Comment: The Py Launcher for Windows (`py.exe`) is indeed typically required for shebangs to work under Windows (though I see them as e.g. `#!/path/to/Python3/` normally, rather than the Unix version you give). `py.exe` comes bundles with (vanilla) [Windows Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and needs to A) be in your Path and B) have the `.py` extension pointing to it for shebangs to run (as far as I am aware). For Anaconda, try looking in %SYSTEMROOT%.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember how I did this. Right click a .py file and choose open with ... "another program on this pc". Then go to your Anaconda3 directory and choose python.exe. Uncheck do this for all option until you know it will work! All my .py files now have a python icon and open with anaconda python when I click on them. (If I right-click I get an option edit with vim.) I never used the #! as in linux. I used the file association. So it makes no difference whether I put in a #! line or not.